# Source control moving from VS2012 to VS2013

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have been using VS2012 Express For Web, and Team Foundation Server for source control. All fine.
Now I'd like to start using VS2013 (Community edition) because it gives better support for JavaScript development. But whenever I open the old project in VS2013, or start a new project in 2013, it always assumes I want to use git repos, whereas I would prefer to use my existing TFS setup.
So, how to change a VS2013 solution from git repos to TFS?

Answer (score 1):

In 'Tools->Options->Source Control', you can change the 'Current source control plug-in' from git to TFS.
You also need to set up your VS2013 to connect to TFS from 'Team->Connect to Team Foundation Server'.

Comment: Thanks, as far as it goes this works. But when I then try to  add a (new)project to source control, and choose the existing TFS, the 'solution explorer' window goes blank - no solution files! Upon closing and re-opening VS2013, everything is set back to using git again! Tried this several times now

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea about this.